# Unique Attribute in WFS Layer

Tags: geoserver, wfs

Can I force an attribute in my WFS Layer to be unique, thus, don't allow mutiple feature with the same value for the attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Not as WFS level as far as I know. If you use a database backend and create an unique constraint for the attribute it naturally guarantees that data that are read through WFS have unique values in this field. For inserts to be done with WFS-T the result of having unique constraint is that if you try to insert a feature with duplicate attribute value, the transaction will fail. Unfortunately the error message which you receive probably does not tell the reason why the transaction was denied.

Comment: the layer is kept in a `dbf`-File. Can I not use unique constraints there?

Comment: I fear you can't.

Comment: Confirmed you can't unless you use a DBMS like PostgreSQL.